# Can I 'return' a result from the main variable?

Tags: c

So I have this exercise where I need to show the N first prime numbers, but I need to specifically create a function to know if the number is a prime number

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int prime(int num){
    int cont,i,j=0,b;

    b=num;

    do{
        j++;
        i=0;
        for(cont=1;cont<j;cont++){
            if(j%cont == 0)
                i++;
        }
        if(i == 1){
            return(j);
            c=j;
            b--;
        }
    } while (b > 0);
}

int main(){
    int *v,n,cont;

    do{
        printf("Input an integer: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    } while (n <= 0);

    v = (int *)malloc(n *  sizeof(int));    

    for(cont=0;cont<n;cont++){
        v[cont] = prime(n);
    }


    for(cont=0;cont<n;cont++){
        printf("%d ",v[cont]);
    }

}
```

The problem with the way i've done this is that the variable J is aways being set to 0 when i call the function again, i've tried to set something like c=j so when the program return to the prime function it would have the 'previous' j value but it gets a weird random number. So I wanted to know if is there a way to 'return' the result in the main function to the prime function, i couldn't find anything that helped me, not that i could understand at least

Comment: First you need to make up your mind whether this is C or C++ and remove the extraneous tag.

Comment: You can move the variable outside of the function, or make it static… it's generally better to just add another argument to your function, though; side-effects can cause issues which are hard to debug as you add more code.

Comment: Your function `prime` forgets to return value at the end. It is UB. Try to trust compiler warnings.

Comment: Change `v[cont] = prime(n)` into `v[cont] = prime(cont)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function prime() is not working as intended and there are many other  errors -

1) Since smallest prime is 2, variable `cont` should start from 2.

2) `scanf` need not be in a loop in this case

3) Enter values in `v` only when `cont` is confirmed a prime.

See this function `prime2`( not optimize though for clarity):

```
bool prime2(int n)
{
    for(int i = 2 ; i<n-1;i++)
        if( n% i == 0) return false;
    return true;
}

int main(){
    int *v,n,cont,cc=0;
    printf("Input range: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    v = malloc(n *  sizeof(int));    

    for(cont=2;cc<n;cont++){
        if( prime2(cont) == true )
        {
            v[cc] = cont;
            cc++;
        }        
    }

    for(cont=0;cont<n;cont++){
        printf("%d ",v[cont]);
    }

    delete v;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, i've just started C and i'm kinda lost but i've managed to make it work, thanks

Comment: Now that you have it kind of working, think about prime numbers a bit more (e.g. when you are checking to see if a number *n* is a prime do you have to check all the way to *n-1*? what about 2,4,6,8,... etc.) can you make prime2 function work faster?

Comment: `v = (int *)malloc(n *  sizeof(int));` -- you don't need to cast the result of `malloc()`, and more idiomatic C code would look like: `v = malloc(sizeof *v  *  n);`. The use of an identifier instead of an explicit type as an operand to `sizeof` is less error-prone and easier to maintain when types change.